# How to get a brand name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
products:id,name,brand_id
variants:id,name,product_id
brands:id,name
```

My sql query for getting a brand's name is:

```
SELECT brands.`name`
FROM brands b
     LEFT JOIN products p ON p.brand_id=b.id
     LEFT JOIN variants v ON p.id=v.product_id AND v.name='test';
```

Is it ok?

```
cause [error]: Unknown column 'brands.name' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the alias that you have specified for the `brands` table:

```
SELECT b.`name`
```